# Proof regarding coin tossed n times with k heads obtained

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-writing, solution-verification

I have to prove that if a coin is tossed n times, then there are $\binom nk$ sequences of possible outcomes in which exactly k heads are obtained.

I have tried to prove it by induction. I would like to know whether my proof is correct (in the sense that it is rigorous and concise). (Note that I am trying to improve my proof writing skills so any suggestion is welcomed.) Thus, if you find any mistake, or manner in which you could have proved the same statement with induction but in a shorter way (yet a more a less rigorous one) do not hesitate to tell me.

So, here is my proof:

Firstly, let us prove the base case n=1. In this case, either k=0 or k=1. If k=0, $\binom{1}{0}=1$, which is true since the only manner is that the coin is tails. (A similar argument works for k=1).

Now suppose that if a coin is tossed n times, then there are $\binom nk$ sequences of possible outcomes in which exactly k heads are obtained. We have to prove that if a coin is tossed n+1 times, then there are $\binom{n+1}{k}$ sequences with k heads. Now, we have that if we fix the last toss such that it is tails, we will have a remaining of n tosses from which we must obtain k heads. By the previous assumption, we know that there are $\binom{n}{k}$ sequences. Now, if the last toss is heads, we will have to choose k-1 remaining heads from the first n positions, which again by the previous assumption, would be $\binom{n}{k-1}$ sequences. Therefore, the total number of sequences are

$$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k-1} = \binom{n+1}{k}$$

by Pascal's formula.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question... How do you have $\binom{n}{k}$ defined?  Why is the result not immediate... just by invoking the definition of binomial coefficients?

Comment: From what I understand, $\binom{n}{k} =\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$.

Comment: While that is a true identity, it is highly uncommon as a *definition*.  Are you using that as your definition?

Comment: I know where you were heading. I was actually trying to prove the question without using that principle but with induction for the sake of proving. (Mainly because I am trying to get better at proof writing and for that matter I wanted to brush upon induction.)

Comment: Although, that being said, I do not think that it is highly uncommon as a definition. For instance, search the definition of **binomial coefficient**.

Comment: You are incorrect in saying that the definition is unequivocally that $\binom{n}{k}$ is defined as notation to be shorthand for $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$.  That is only one way of defining it.  If you choose to define it that way then you can prove after the fact that it happens to be useful for counting subsets.  On the other hand, if you were to instead define it as being the number of subsets... you can prove that it equals $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$.  It is a chicken-egg scenario.  The question is which comes first.

Comment: While you can prove that all of the definitions eventually are equivalent to one another... one must still choose a starting point to go from.  This is just like in trying to define $e$ as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ or in defining $e$ to be $1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}+\dots$ or defining $e$ to be the number such that $\dfrac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$.  We need a starting point to work with.

Comment: The question is whether you are approaching this from a combinatorial perspective or from an algebraic perspective.  If you are approaching from a combinatorial perspective then there is nothing to prove since what you are asking to prove is just a rephrasing of the definition.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I see eye to eye with you. I was trying to approach it from the algebraic definition

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so much effort is needed to prove this, as this is just the definition of combinations.

---

The definition of $\binom{n}{k}$ is not $\frac{n!}{(n-k)! \times k!}$, that's just a formula to calculate it. The conceptual meaning of $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to PICK (or choose) $k$ things out of $n$, regardless of which order you pick them in.

---

To elaborate, let's take an example. Let's say you have $5$ balls called A, B, C, D, and E in a bag. You have to select out $2$ of these balls. "choosing" $A, B$ is the same thing as choosing $B, A$, because the order you pull them out from the bag does not matter. Now you can implement the formula, as it is understood why combinations is applied here instead of permutations. Based on the question you asked and your comment that says "From what I understand, $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! \times k!}$", it seems like you haven't understood combinations in depth and memorized the formula to calculate it. I have provided a proof for the formula in the last section of this post, so that you can understand the conceptual meaning of combinations and why the formula works.

---

So, if we translate your problem in  terms of our example, it says that we have $n$ balls this time called $1, 2, 3, \dots, n$. We have to pick and keep out $k$ of these $n$ balls out of the bag, regardless of which order we pick the $k$. We will call the balls we take out of the bag heads, and the remaining balls inside the bag tails. Because of our explanation in the above section, we can similarly use combinations here and not permutations. So it's simply $\binom{n}{k}$.

---

Basically restating my response to your post, this is just the definition of combinations applied to a problem. No need to use induction or anything else.

---

Now, as I said in the second section, I will give the proof of why the formula works.

Taking our example again, say you have a bag with $n$ balls in it, and you have to tell the number of ways you can choose a.k.a select a.k.a pick $k$ balls out of the bag, regardless of which order you pick the balls in. If the order you pick them would matter, then we would have $n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-(k-1)) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ways to do it because there are $n$ ways to pick the first ball, and now there are $n-1$ balls left in the bag. Then, there are $n-1$ ways, and so on. However, in the real problem order does NOT matter. In the $\frac{n!}{k!}$ count, any group of $k$ balls have been counted $k!$ times as there are $k!$ ways to decide which order we will pick some given $k$ balls in, and we have counted all of those $k!$ ways. However, we only want to count all these $k!$ outcomes as $1$ outcome, since order doesn't matter in combinations. So we have to divide the original count by $k!$, and we get $\frac{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}}{k!} = \boxed{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\times k!}}$

$\blacksquare$

---

**Hopefully, after reading my entire post, you have gotten a in-depth understanding of the conceptual meaning of combinations and the proof of the formula of it**.